# Release Interface pointers

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, atl

I have some smart pointers declared as member variables inside a class in the destructor of the class , while freeing this interfaces, which code is better:

member varible

```
CComQIPtr<IMyInterFace> m_pMyInterface;
```

constructor

```
m_pMyInterface.CreateInstace(CLSID_MyInterface);
```

in Destructor

```
if(m_pMyInterface)
    m_pMyInterface.Release();
```

or should this be

```
if(m_pMyInterface.p ! = NULL)
    m_pMyInterface.Release();
```

Form the above which one is better and is there any flaw in the way i am using the interface pointers.
regards
tom

Comment: `if(m_pMyInterface) m_pMyInterface.Release();` is enough.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular smart pointer, but if it's 'smart', should it not release automatically in the destructor?

Comment: @Bgie: It does as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~CComQIPtr` destructor takes care of everything. You don't need to release explicitly. If you however want to, e.g. to reuse the variable, you can do either of the two:

- `m_pMyInterface.Release();`
- `m_pMyInterface = NULL;` (operator `=` works with `CComPtr`, might be ambiguous with `CComQIPtr`)

NULL checking is not necessary, `CComQIPtr::Release` method does it anyway.

Comment: will there be a scenario where the m_pMyInterface pointer is NULL but m_pMyInterface.p is not NULL and vice-versa

Comment: It's impossible. `.p` is the real holder of the pointer, and the class on top just helps managing the same value. You don't need to touch `.p` directly ever, work with the wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

They are equivalent, though I really don't like someone writing a book just for the sake of it.
Also, the `Release()` call is unneeded, just let the destructor handle it.

Go for the short one.